# Problem trying to create Sequence Container

Tags: ssis, control-flow

I am new to SSIS. I am using BIDS 2005.  When I am not in the debugging mode, I select the Control Flow tab, go to the Toolbox and click on a Sequence Container. I then drag it out on to the design surface. As I drag, my cursor is showing a "plus" sign as though it is going to let me create a new instance of the Sequence Container. However, when I let go of the mouse button, the "plus" disappears and there is no Sequence Container.

What is really odd is that I already have one Sequence Containter on the surface and all I want to do is create a second one.

Am I doing something wrong?  Why can't I get the new instance?  Is there a limit to how many Sequencer Containers exist on the surface?

-- Puzzled

Comment: Disregard my post.  I found out that I could double-click on the Sequence Container in the Toolbox and it put an instance on the surface.  I was used to dragging all the other controls I had used and was not expecting this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try to double click on an item. It should then appear in a control flow page. It worked for me :)

Regards,
Jambis